# Operador en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Que significa este "operador" **:=** ?... 
Actualmente trabajo en sql server y al momento de hacer esta pregunta estaba indagando en otras paginas sobre consultas en **SQL Server** encontre aquel "*operador*" de la pregunta, desesperado lo copié en mi gestor de base de datos para probarlo en mi consulta, a lo que saco un error sobre éste "*operador*" e inmediatamente quise pregunta aqui. En fin, solo queria aclarar para que servia, que hacia y como lo podia utlizar a mi favor, nada mas.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: Ese operador no existe en SQL Server, lo que significaría, de encontrarse, es un error de sintaxis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dicho operador no existe en SQL Server, si lo encuentras en un query o procedure obtendrás un Syntax Error.

Sin embargo, en Pascal, Modula-2, MySQL, etc, es un operador de asignación.

Aquí un ejemplo de su uso en MySQL

```
SELECT @ejemplo := 'hola';    /*variable 'ejemplo' ahora tiene el valor de 'hola'*/
return value: 'hola'
```

Answer (score 3):

El operador := es un asignador y se utiliza en algunos lenguajes como en MySQL y Postgres, pero no en SQL Server. Ahí se asigna con el símbolo "="

Comment: Esta mal visto pedir puntos en la publicaciones. Sin embargo, puedes invitar al usuario a hacer el [tour] para que sepa como funcionamos ;)

Comment: Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Gracias gbianchi, no sabía que no se podía pedir puntos. El tema es que sueles dedicar tiempo a responder  y en muchos casos no dan ni las gracias.